# Angular custom library - is not a function error

Tags: angular, shared-libraries

I've create a custom library, built it, and added it to my main project. I've followed the directions for creating a shown in the angular documentation.
When I try to call a function in the library, it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: this.mmLibSvc.isAuthenticated() is not a function
```

Here is the service class from my library MmLib:

```
export class MmLibService {
  isAuthenticated() { return false; }   
}
```

public_api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/mm-lib.service';
```

mm-lib.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MmLibComponent],
  imports: [ ],
  exports: [MmLibComponents]
})
export class MmLibModule {}
```

I've have built the library and added MmLib folder to node_modules folder under my project.

Under my project:
app.module.ts:

```
import { MmLibService } from 'mm-lib'
...
providers: [MmLibService, ...] ,
imports: [MmLibModule, ...]
...
```

Projects AuthService:

```
import { MmLibService } from 'mm-lib';

constructor(private mmLibSvc: MmLibService){}

public useAuth() {
  return this.mmLibSvc.isAuthenticated();
}
```

The error occurs at

```
return this.mmLibSvc.isAuthenticated();
```

I have included the service under app.module.ts. The module and service import and are recognized, it even shows the function definition with I F12 in vscode. Is there something special I need to do in order to use a function in a custom library?  I know the library is working because I can one of its components.

Comment: Not enough code to help you here. You're probably exporting/importing things incorrectly.

Comment: Updated with code example

Comment: Looks like your export is incorrect. try `export { MmLibService }` instead of `export class ...`. I would always run a `console.log(<service>);` where you're trying to import the exported class from. Sometimes it's hard to tell what is actually being exported/imported so spitting it out to the console will at least give you the value of it (so you can sniff the object and see what you need to fix)

Comment: in `export class`  code sample is creating a class. I wouldn't be able to do `export { MmLibService }` there. I trying a console.log on the service, it appears it is referencing the correct library, although I do see a TypeError: 'caller', 'callee'.. error